# Почему не работает resize в jquery 3.1.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Была дана задача (Высота карточек в ОДНОМ ряду должна быть одинаковой и не влиять на другие ряды. Другими словами принимается максимальная высота карточки ряда для остальных карточек ряда).

Задачу я выполнил, но встретился с такой проблемой, что в jquery 3.1.0 не работает resize, а в jquery 1.11.1 всё работает как и должно. Аналогичная ситуация на **jsfiddle . net**. если я там выбираю jquery 3.1.0 то resize не работает. О_о что-то поменялось? Почему resize не работает jquery 3.1.0?

Comment: всё работает в штатном режиме https://jsfiddle.net/mokh1pjc/  видимо у вас ошибка в коде

Comment: Какая может быть ошибка если в 3,1,0 не работает, а в 1,11,1 работает О_О

Comment: вот ссылка в комментарии выше.. там всё работает... как может ТАМ работать, а у вас не работать?

Comment: Я через час скину скрипт.